# How to write Junit test case for old java project?

Tags: java, junit

I am working on a very old application built using strut 1.1 in 2004. The complete application is made by combining three projects(common, web, and EJB) in Eclipse and all these three are packaged as.EAR file. So here the confusion where to fit the JUnit test cases for this type of structure.

Whether I should create a separate project for writing the test cases. If I create the separate project, I would add the above projects in the build path.

So what is the right way? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Also, tell me about the way I can check the results on GUI that how many cases are passed and how many are failed.

Comment: you are now going to write unit tests for a project written in 2004?

Comment: @Stultuske He didn't say **unit** tests.

Comment: @GhostCat even if it are integration or service tests, this seems to be a bit redundant.

Comment: @Stultuske See my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all: in case you intend to write real JUnit **unit** tests for 14 year old code, the answer is: do **not** do that.

If at all, you should be using JUnit as environment to automate test case execution, which in this case should be "integration" or "functional" tests.

You see: the only reasonable argument to invest money in old, existing source code is: you intend to refactor/replace that solution with a new implementation. Then your one and only concern is that your new code behaves like the old one. From a functional point of view. It doesn't make sense to invest time/energy into unit testing units you intend to throw away soon.

Beyond that: do whatever works for you. Typically, it would be better to have a complete new project to avoid tampering anything existing.

Comment: ... what he said :)